# How do I select text in the vim command line?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to select / yank text from the vim command line?  I know that you can put text (with `ctrl+r`) into the command line, but I have not yet found a way to yank from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open the command-line window with `q:` and visually select/yank like you would do in normal mode. If you are in the middle of writing a command, `<C-f>` opens the command-line window with your current command.